# Angular typescript error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I make a service to get data from back-end as the pre-defined model then I call the data into my component, however, I got the error that I could not solve it after doing research on the Internet. The error happens in my component when I try to pass data into an empty string that I declared before.

This is my service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ORIGIN_URL, API_PREFIX } from '../shared/constants/baseurl.constants';
import { History } from '../models/history';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HistoricalBpiService {

  private apiUrl: string;

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    @Inject(ORIGIN_URL) private baseUrl: string,
    @Inject(API_PREFIX) private apiPrefix: string
  ) {
    this.apiUrl = baseUrl + apiPrefix;
  }

  oneYear(): Observable<History[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'data/history/365')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json() as History[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

This is the model:

```
export interface History {
    date: string;
    value: number;
}
```

This is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { HistoricalBpiService } from '../../services/historical-bpi.service';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { History } from '../../models/history';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  history: History[] = [];

  public lineChartData: any = [
    { data: [], label: 'BTC' }
  ];

  public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(
    private historicalBpiService: HistoricalBpiService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {}

  oneYear() {
    this.historicalBpiService.oneYear()
      .subscribe((data: History[]) => {
        this.history = data;
        for (let i of this.history) {
          this.lineChartData[0].data = i.value;
          this.lineChartLabels = i.date; // THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR !!!
        }
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      // Default chart
      this.oneYear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please mark if the answee helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `i.date` is a `string`, because `this.lineChartLabels` is an `Array<any>` you can't assign a string to it.

Best to push instead of assign:

```
this.lineChartLabels.push(i.date)
```

Comment: is not the same answer posted below

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you are trying to assign a string to the type of any, 
You need to push the string to the array,

```
this.lineChartLabels.push(i.date);
```